# In Ruby Can I override the ternary operator '?'

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading, overriding

In Ruby, Can I override the ternary operator '?'

Comment: Show an example of what you want (even though the answer is no, you can't change how the ternary operator works).

Comment: I suppose, this is pure 'academical' question.

Comment: Overriding operators is a double-edged sword. Operators have assumed behaviors, and changing those can lead to very subtle and hard to find bugs. It's something you do carefully, and document heavily, so you, or someone coming after you, can understand what's happening.

Comment: in maths, you often have operations of higher arities. An example of ternary operation is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation . You could have something like `def three_times i ; i*3 ; end ; 0: 4 ? three_times ` to sum  `0, 3, 6, 9, 12`.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't: `?:` is not a method, so you can't redefine it.

[This](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Operator_Precedence#Operator_Precedence_Table) operator precedence table shows which operators are really methods, and hence available to be overridden.